# Sort Arrays by Length of Sub-Array Key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to sort the following array from largest to smallest based on the length of the keys in the key value pairs:

```
[["Hello":"Goodbye"],["Yes":"No"],["He is going":"She is going"]]
```

This is the code that I am using that is not working:

```
makeArray.sort(function (a, b) {
      return Object.keys(b).length - Object.keys(a).length;
    });
console.log(makeArray);
```

I want the console.log to read:

```
[["He is going":"She is going"],["Hello":"Goodbye"],["Yes":"No"]]
```

Comment: That is not valid... Should be `[{"Hello":"Goodbye"},{...`

Comment: My mistake!  Just corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting the number of keys, not looking at the first key. So you were close, just need to reference the first index of the key array.

```js
var makeArray = [{"Hello":"Goodbye"},{"Yes":"No"},{"He is going":"She is going"}];

makeArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return Object.keys(b)[0].length - Object.keys(a)[0].length;
});
console.log(makeArray);
```

---

But with your comments, I do not think you have objects.

```js
var makeArray = [
  ["Hello", "Goodbye"],
  ["Yes", "No"],
  ["He is going", "She is going"]
];

makeArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b[0].length - a[0].length;
});
console.log(makeArray);
```

Comment: Hm, this still isn't working when I load it into my app...

It's just spitting out the same order as the input.

Comment: This is the input I tried: 

0: "Dortmund in"
1: "Dortmund, en"

and this is the second key/value going in:

0: "Dortmund in the"
1: "Dortmund, en el"

And the order stays the same.

Comment: Am I formatting the array in the my example improperly?

Comment: The console.log of the entire array looks like: [Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]

Comment: Ok, I was getting confused when, initially, the others were telling me I formatted the array incorrectly.  It is now, again, an array with sub-arrays.